# PyCharm Vagrant Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter

Tags: python, vagrant, pycharm

I configured remote Python interpreter 3 months ago with Vagrant, when I was using it, everything was fine, for the last two days I am receiving `Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter`  error very frequently, as on the video: http://take.ms/0Mr8b

I am not sure what might be error for this.

Environment:
Vagrant Ver.2.0.0

`PyCharm 2017.3.3 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-173.4301.16, built on January 11, 2018
Licensed to my name 
Subscription is active until May 23, 2018
For educational use only.
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b11 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.3`

Comment: For future reference... deleting and re-adding the remote interpreter could help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is solved by `File-> Invalidate Caches & Restart` in my case as suggested by youtrack forum

Answer (score 3):

It is solved by cleaning ***.pycharm_helpers*** folder on remote interpreter.

```
rm -rf ~/.pycharm_helpers
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to remove the `Visible only for this project` flag from the `Deployment configuration` that was attached to the remote interpreter. Then I invalidated the cache and restarted as suggested by the other answer.