# PyCharm - How to debug "Pycharm Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter"

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to use PyCharm with a remote interpreter (SSH to be precise) but I'm receiving the error `Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter`.

This problem has been discussed many times on Stack Overflow (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964000/pycharm-couldnt-refresh-skeletons-for-remote-interpreter), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007292/pycharm-vagrant-couldnt-refresh-skeletons-for-remote-interpreter)). However, those questions are too specific e.g addressing particular installation processes. What I want to know is, in general, how does one debug this error? How can I find more information about what causes it? Or what fixes it?

As far as I can tell, PyCharm does not provide additional information for why the error occurs, although maybe I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem at some point and tried the solutions suggested in similar questions, but what worked for me in the end was updating Pycharm to the latest version (so at least in my case it was probably a bug that Pycharm had, which got fixed)